# Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime : Method not found

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

When I am trying "Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime" command constantly getting below error.

> Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime : Method not found:
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IAttributeProvider
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty.get_AttributeProvider()'.
>   At C:\Users\ravi\source\repos\test.ps1:12 char:5
>   +     Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime `
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmData...egrationRuntime], MissingMethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.SetAzureDataFactoryIntegrationRuntimeCommand

When I ran "Get-Module" command I see below list of modules

> ModuleType Version    Name
>   ExportedCommands
>
> ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
>
> Script     **0.5.10**     **AzureRM.DataFactoryV2**
>   {Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2, Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun,
>   Get-AzureRmDat...
>
> Script     **5.6.0**      **AzureRM.profile**
>   {Add-AzureRmEnvironment, Clear-AzureRmContext, Clear-AzureRmDefault,
>   Connect-A...
>
> Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
>   {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
>
> Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
>   {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString, Get-Acl,
>   Get-AuthenticodeSi...
>
> Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member,
>   Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
>
> Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management
>   {Connect-WSMan, Disable-WSManCredSSP, Disconnect-WSMan,
>   Enable-WSManCredSSP...}
>
> Script     0.2.0      PowerShellEditorServices.Commands
>   {ConvertFrom-ScriptExtent, ConvertTo-ScriptExtent, Find-Ast,
>   Get-Token...}
>
> Script     0.2.0      PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode
>   {Close-VSCodeHtmlContentView, New-VSCodeHtmlContentView,
>   Set-VSCodeHtmlContent...

I have installed Azure PowerShell MSI link given on below page.

Page URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/other-install?view=azurermps-6.9.0

MSI URL: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v6.9.0-September2018/azure-powershell.6.9.0.msi

Update:
When I was trying to create IS manually I see that its created but with "Unavailable" status

[image]

Updated on 10/10 for Joy Wang
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I test the `Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime` on my side, it works fine. I recommend you to remove the modules and install again,  refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.9.0).

**My specific command**:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName 'joywebapp' -DataFactoryName 'joyfactoryv2' -Name 'integrationRuntime35' -Type "SelfHosted" -Description 'New description111'
```

[image]

**My module** :

[image]

> When I was trying to create IS manually I see that its created but with "Unavailable" status

To fix this issue of `Self-Hosted` type runtime, you could install the **Microsoft Integration Runtime Configuration Manager**, in the runtime -> Edit -> Click here to launch the express setup for this computer, refer to the screenshot.

[image]

After installing it, you will see them like the screenshot.

[image]

**Check in the portal**:

[image]

Comment: I reinstalled with "Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber" and Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime still gives me the same error.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Did you `Import-Module AzureRM`?

Comment: When I did Get-Module from VSC I see "AzureRM.DataFactoryV2" and "AzureRM.profile" but did not explicity loadded module. But I can give it a try.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati It is unreasonable, your modules are the same with me. On my side, all work fine. You could check the second part of my answer for your update question first, if it is helpful, you could up-vote it.

Comment: One of thing that is strange to me is this, on regular powershell prompt Get-Module doesn't give "AzureRM.DataFactoryV2" and "AzureRM.profile". Same behaviour is for powershell prompt on visual studio code. After I ran my script on Visual Studio code I see those two modules are loded. Is this behavour is normal. Updating my question with screenshot.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati It is normal, to check the module if exists, you could find it in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

Comment: why the module doesn't show up when I do Get-Modules on regular PowerShell prompt?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati I am not sure, but it is normal, on my side, same with you. Just check it in the `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Also, you can try to remove the windows powershell and install again, PS: I use windows powershell ISE.

Comment: Let me give it a try in Windows PowerShell ISE

Comment: @RaviKhambhati what is your powershell version, use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` check it.

Comment: Just now I tried to do the same on one of the other machine where I have older version of AzureRM and it worked there. AzureRM.DataFactoryV2(0.5.3) and AzureRM.Profile(4.6.0)(PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012)

Comment: PowerShell version is 5.1.14393.2485

Comment: @RaviKhambhati ok, seems some weird things to the machine, I think the modules and ps version are all fine.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati I recommend you to open a issue in the [github](https://github.com/azure/azure-powershell/issues), if my reply is helpful, you could mark or upvote it.

Comment: I have already created issue on github https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16432